# Odoo 16 Custom Module for changing the Theme Colors

Tags: odoo, themes, odoo-16

I want to create a module for Odoo 16 to change the Theme Colors.
But have no idea why i can't install the module always comes with this fault:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 85, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "<decorator-gen-6>", line 2, in __getitem__
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/tools/func.py", line 87, in locked
    return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 34, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj]
KeyError: ('ir.model.data', <function IrModelData._xmlid_lookup at 0x7f580a33d750>, 'web._assets_primary_variables')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 698, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 676, in _tag_template
    return self._tag_record(record)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 568, in _tag_record
    f_val = self.id_get(f_ref, raise_if_not_found=nodeattr2bool(rec, 'forcecreate', True))
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 681, in id_get
    res = self.model_id_get(id_str, raise_if_not_found)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 687, in model_id_get
    return self.env['ir.model.data']._xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(id_str, raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 2018, in _xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
    return self._xmlid_lookup(xmlid)[1:3]
  File "<decorator-gen-40>", line 2, in _xmlid_lookup
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 90, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 2011, in _xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: web._assets_primary_variables

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/http.py", line 1584, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/service/model.py", line 133, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/http.py", line 1611, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/http.py", line 1809, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 235, in _dispatch
    response = super()._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 154, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/http.py", line 697, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 46, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 33, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/api.py", line 461, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/api.py", line 448, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-74>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 76, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 491, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 615, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in new
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/tools/func.py", line 87, in locked
    return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 90, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 487, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 371, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 230, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 71, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 763, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 829, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 749, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "/opt/odoo16/chnOdooProd/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 711, in _tag_root
    raise ParseError('while parsing %s:%s, somewhere inside\n%s' % (
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing None:3, somewhere inside
<data inherit_id="web._assets_primary_variables">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="/chn_color_theme/static/src/scss/theme.css"/>
        </xpath>
    </data>

The above server error caused the following client error:
RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
    at makeErrorFromResponse (http://192.168.0.208:8069/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:10237:19) (/web/static/src/core/network/rpc_service.js:34)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://192.168.0.208:8069/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:10290:27) (/web/static/src/core/network/rpc_service.js:87)
```

This is my ****manyfest**.py** :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': 'CHN Color Themes',
    'version': '16.0.1',
    'author': '',
    'license': 'AGPL-3',
    'summary': 'Color Themes',
    'sequence': 2,
    'description': """ Color Themes """,
    'category': 'Themes',
    'website': '',
    'depends': ['web'],
    'data': [
      'views/assets.xml',
    ],
    'assets': {
    'web._assets_primary_variables': [
        'web/static/src/scss/primary_variables.scss',
    ],
    }
}
```

This is my **assets.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="assets_primary_variables" inherit_id="web._assets_primary_variables">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="/chn_color_theme/static/src/scss/theme.css"/>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

This is my **theme.css**

```
$o-community-color: #71639e;
$o-brand-odoo: $o-community-color;
$o-brand-primary: $o-community-color;
```

Can someone help me by doing that?
Or is there a better way to change the theme Color? I don't want to buy an app from the store.
Chat-GPT has always said that I can't reach the web._assets_primary_variables, but in the manifest is the depends set on the web.
Thanks

Comment: i have try to reference the origianl file. I have read in other blogs that someone has the same problem with that and the solution at him was the 'assets': {

Comment: In odoo 16 you don't need to put XML so remove it, and the path should be mentioned in the asset as you did but not sure why you added primary_asses you should have put 
`chn_color_theme/static/src/scss/theme.css` there

Comment: Or you can use this free [APP](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/themes/16.0/backend_theme_infinito/#)